# Why my raspberry does not respond?

Tags: raspbian, ssh

i have on Raspberry Pi 2 installed Raspbian (i have on it installet also htop,iceweasel,xrdp and sometimes chromium).
Everytime when i run iceweasel and around 15 pages with autosurfs raspberry,after few days is my iceweasel powered off (maybe shutdown) and when i connect to raspberry via xrdp and click to everything,nothing happen.. i can just open Menu but that is all what i can.
I cannot also open terminal,when i power off raspberry and connect it to TV via HDMI it shows many errors [FAILED] every time when it try to do something.. 
Please,what can i do ?

Comment: How much current does your power supply provide? For more heavy usage a phone charger etc may not be enough.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a bit like the system perhaps ran out of memory, causing it to freeze up for a while, you ended up yanking the power, and somewhere in there the root filesystem got corrupted, which is why boot services are now failing.

You could search through `/var/log/syslog` for `oom_killer` to see if an out-of-memory event is reported there.  There are timestamps in that file, so you could also look through the time period this occurred to see if there's any clue about the cause.

You could try running `e2fsck` on the second partition, although likely this has already happened.  You can do this in another linux box, or, if you can get the pi to boot, as root:

```
echo "-y" > /forcefsck
```

`sudo` will not work in this instance.  You could do this with `sudoedit` or whatever other means; the point is to create a file, `/forcefsck`, with one line, `-y`.  The reboot the pi.

If that does not work, you'll have to restore the system from your backup, or, if you don't have one, from a fresh image.

Comment: Thanks,maybe it will be the main problem.. I will try to resolve it.   MUCH THANKS!